# MySQL InnoDB Index in swap

Tags: mysql, replication, innodb

I can't find any info regarding my question. This is more theoretical question.
For example, i have table **keywords**.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `keywords` (
  `kid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `language_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `keyword` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`kid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `custom_idx` (`language_id`,`keyword`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

My server has 1GB of free RAM memory. My table has millions of rows and size of my **custom_idx** is more than 1GB. *Index can't fit into RAM memory*. What would mysql do ? Is only part of this index will be stored in the memory ? Will this break BTREE/Clustered index performance dramatically ?

Also, if size of my index can't fit into **innodb_buffer_pool_size** limits, what would happen ?

Is replication is the answer to enormous InnoDB databases where indexes can't fit into RAM memory ?

Comment: I have checked in hexa view how is doing the MYISAM: separate files and indexing. That "egnine" can be done in InnoDB to, but I didn't checked at low level how is doing, so I don't know the answer for your question, but: from my experience on those large databases it is much better other DB, wich starts with "O" and ends with "racle" :)  for me the 1 million is the limit: under that mysql above that other db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InnoDB uses the InnoDB buffer pool (whose size is controlled using the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` variable) to cache a lot of different data structures, including row data and indexes. If your data set is too large for this buffer pool, MySQL will of course swap. How dramatic the effects are, you'll have to measure. It can be anything between "barely noticeable" and "queries take 1000x longer".

Replication is most certainly not a solution. Replication only syncs your data to another machine, and it doesn't allow schema differences (e.g., different indexes, if you had that in mind) between them. If that other machine is equally underequipped, you'll come out with two instead of one slow database servers. You should probably install more memory into the first server.

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB loads into memory as much data as it can. In case it does not fit in the memory - well, it does not load it. This has 2 side effects. First is that if it need to lookup data that's not in the RAM, it has to load it from the disk. But it first need to flush back to disk any changed data, that is in the memory. Also, if any unique index can not fit in memory, then when you are trying to insert/update row, the index should be read from the disk; this is one of the first noticable performance problems - slow inserts when unique indexes cannot fit in memory, because it is one of the few conditions in which all index values should be read.

Not replication, but sharding / partitioning is the way to fit the dataset in the RAM of different servers.